# Sharepoint Online Encountering Error while attempting to create a new Page Layout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, page-layout, design-manager

I am currently trying to use the Design Manager to create a new Page Layout.

When I click the `Create a page layout` link I receive an error popup:

> "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred."

I just created a new publishing site collection and I'm trying to experiment with new page layouts.